# TLS Negotiation, need help understanding

Tags: grpc, tls1.2, tls1.3

We have an app that is using gRPC and trying to communicate over TLS. I'm trying to sort out an issue where I believe the TLS Negotiation is failing because the client is trying to use a version not support by the server. I've done a Wireshark capture and I'm seeing the beginning of the Handshake listing TLS version 1.0.  After that the Client Hello shows 1.2. I'm not sure I'm reading these captures correctly. Below is a snippet of the capture. Am I seeing this correctly?

```
TLSv1.3 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
Content Type: Handshake (22)
Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
Length: 512
Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
    Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
    Length: 508
    Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
    Random: f7c1a36756c74fb8a1e4e4e12770832c15bcc10149988b0a2822dbc176eee3ab
    Session ID Length: 32
    Session ID: d01cc92dfdc7c404c1f1644e204f494f5a39d4352ccedfb8633cba5476353082
    Cipher Suites Length: 14
    Cipher Suites (7 suites)
    Compression Methods Length: 1
    Compression Methods (1 method)
    Extensions Length: 421
    Extension: server_name (len=18) name=tlstestserver
    Extension: extended_master_secret (len=0)
    Extension: renegotiation_info (len=1)
    Extension: supported_groups (len=4)
    Extension: ec_point_formats (len=2)
    Extension: session_ticket (len=0)
    Extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation (len=14)
    Extension: signature_algorithms (len=20)
    Extension: next_protocol_negotiation (len=0)
    Extension: key_share (len=71) secp256r1
    Extension: psk_key_exchange_modes (len=2)
    Extension: supported_versions (len=5) TLS 1.3, TLS 1.2
    Extension: padding (len=232)
```

Comment: It's possible that the TLS handshake is failing due to some kind of version mismatch between the client and server, but I think we need more information to be able to deduce this. :)

The line `Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)` is not an issue - that is hardcoded for interop reasons. Your ClientHello message from the capture indicates that the client supports TLS 1.2 and 1.3. Could you share more of the capture?

Also, can you share the error messages you're getting from the client or server side?